# What does this prefix (ABF:) in the MS Access SQL query mean?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am tasked with extracting some data from an obscure MSACCESS 2000 Program that is linked with mySQL tables and showing the data via PHP instead so we can scrap the access program for good.

I have no Access experience and I have searched hours for the origin of some data fields now, the closest I've come is generating a report on the form and it shows me the following (table/col names edited):

```
SELECT [Table1].[somecol],
[Table2].[somecol],
[Table2].[somecol],
[ABF: Table3].[somecol],
[ABF: Table3].[somecol],
[ABF: Table3].[somecol]
FROM
[Table2]
INNER JOIN
([ABF: Table3]
INNER JOIN [Table1]
ON [ABF: Table3].[somecol]=[Table1].[somecol])
ON [Table2].[somecol]=[Table1].[somecol];
```

What does the **ABF:** mean?!?

Table3 does not show up anywhere in the mySQL DB AFAIK. It doesn't seem to be linked in any .mdb data either.

Could it be Abfrage (Query)? This is a German Access. If so, where the heck do I find that sub query that spits out **Table3** in the end? Navigation in this ancient Access is a nightmare and you can't search for anything globally...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It most certainly is short for **Abfrage** (Query).

There is no `Table3`, and it is no subquery.
There is a query in the Access db with the name `ABF: Table3`.

Look into its design to see what it does.

Or use `? CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ABF: Table3").SQL` in the Immediate window.

Comment: The QueryDefs command did it for me, I can finally see what is actually happening under the surface and replicate the query in PHP. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`ABF:` has no special meaning in MS Access - in your example it is merely part of the table/query name, e.g.: `ABF: Table3`. I could equally create a new database and save a query called `QRY: MyTable`.

As you've indicated, `ABF` is likely an abbreviation for `Abfrage`, the German for `Query`, and so I would suggest looking through the queries within your database for a query called `ABF: Table3`.

Note that queries may be hidden in MS Access, and therefore you may need to enable **Show Hidden Objects** within the Options menu before the query is displayed in the MS Access navigation.